# where does docker attach volume on host machine when its not specified?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

when you specify docker volume like this:

```
volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
```

where does it store on host?

I'm using docker on mac, and things are way more complicated than on linux

In docs it just says: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

`volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql`

which is in no way clear to me.

from what I can figure it was mounted on the virtual box vm

[image]

is this correct?

Comment: read this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the related document first: [Docker Data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/)

#### Explanation

Simple way to understand the volume is, if you knew about Unix/Linux, you can think these volumes are seperate filesystem (UFS) similar as in physical server world, you create server with different /, /usr, /home, etc in different ufs with different folders, not only one root `/`' folder.

with

```
volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
```

or `-v /var/lib/mysql` in `docker run` command, you should have a seperate folder for it, when you login the docker container and `df -k` on it

So we can make a Demo to understand how it works.

Run a container without option `-v /var/lib/mysql`

```
$ docker run -ti --rm alpine sh
/ # df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
none                  61886452   7996664  50723068  14% /
tmpfs                  1024828         0   1024828   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1024828         0   1024828   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996664  50723068  14% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996664  50723068  14% /etc/hostname
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996664  50723068  14% /etc/hosts
shm                      65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1024828         0   1024828   0% /proc/kcore
/ #
```

Then run the container with `-v /var/lib/mysql`

```
$ docker run -ti -v /var/lib/mysql --rm alpine sh
/ # df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
none                  61886452   7996700  50723032  14% /
tmpfs                  1024828         0   1024828   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1024828         0   1024828   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996700  50723032  14% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996700  50723032  14% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996700  50723032  14% /etc/hostname
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996700  50723032  14% /etc/hosts
shm                      65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1024828         0   1024828   0% /proc/kcore
/ #
```

Now you see the volume is set as

```
/dev/vda2             61886452   7996700  50723032  14% /var/lib/mysql
```

You can mount your local disk to that volume with :

```
-v /src/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Or in docker-compose:

```
volumes:
    - /src/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

It will mount the host's `/src/mysql` to container's `/var/lib/mysql`

Hope I have explained enough for your question.